# Unable to install mongodb on ubuntu 16.10

Tags: software-installation, 16.10, mongodb

I have tried installing mongodb using official repos but I always get the same error.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6

echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list

sudo apt-get udate

sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

But the package manager is unable to find and install mongodb-org:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org

Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho

Creando árbol de dependencias       

Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho

E: No se ha podido localizar el paquete mongodb-org
```

I followed the instructions of the official documentation without success.

> Linux Ubuntu-WS 4.8.0-32-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 13 14:30:16 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: Was there an error when running `sudo apt-get update`? I'm pretty sure you want this URL in the `echo` command instead: `http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/xenial/mongodb-org/3.5/`.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Before making the change there was no error, but then there was a certificate error. I'm thinking it's an arch error.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know there is no package for mongo 3.4 in 16.10 yet.
 You can only get 2.4 from ubuntu packages http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/mongodb 
just run

> sudo apt install mongodb-server

Answer (score 1):

pre-installation:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927 
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list 
sudo apt-get update
```

The error comes from the -y flag:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Instead, you can use:

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
```

and than manualy accept, or to allow unauthenticated by:

```
sudo apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated mongodb-org
```